# Count Grouped Gaps In Time For Time Range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking to find how many grouped gaps exist for a given time range.

```
starting range: 2012-01-12 00:00:00
  ending range: 2012-01-18 59:59:59
```

Which translates roughly to:

```
type  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
a        |--========]
a                             |==------]
b                 |==============--]
c     |-----===========]
d        |--=====================------]
```

the same data grouped by type:

```
a        |--========]         |==------]
b                 |==============--]
c     |-----===========]
d        |--=====================------]
```

Resulting in:

```
type  gap
---------
a     1  (yes)
b     1  (yes)
c     1  (yes)
d     0  (no)
```

And eventually...

```
SUM(gap) AS gaps
----------------
3
```

**UPDATE for clarification:**

Data is stored with start and end timestamps per type. For example:

```
id  type  start_datetime       end_datetime
--------------------------------------------------
1   a     2012-01-11 00:00:00  2012-01-14 59:59:59
2   a     2012-01-18 00:00:00  2012-01-20 59:59:59
3   b     2012-01-14 00:00:00  2012-01-19 59:59:59
4   c     2012-01-10 00:00:00  2012-01-15 59:59:59
5   d     2012-01-11 00:00:00  2012-01-20 59:59:59
```

Comment: How is your data actually stored?  What is the table definition, etc?

Comment: Start timestamp and end timestamp. I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: Can start and end time be any time, or are they always midnight?

Comment: Can time ranges for the same type overlap?

Comment: @MarkBannister Start and end time may be any time. I simplified it for the example.

Comment: @MarkBannister Yes. Time ranges for the same type may overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a variant on wildplasser's answer that uses windows instead of a CTE. Based on the same test fixture:

```
select ztype, count(*) as gaps
from (
    select ztype, datetime, sum(n) over(partition by ztype order by datetime asc) as level
    from (
        select id, ztype, start_datetime as datetime, 1 as n from tmp.gaps
        union all
        select id, ztype, end_datetime, -1 from tmp.gaps
        union all
        select 0, ztype, '2012-01-12 00:00:00', 0 from (select distinct ztype from tmp.gaps) z
        union all
        select 0, ztype, '2012-01-19 00:00:00', 0 from (select distinct ztype from tmp.gaps) z
    ) x
) x
where level = 0 and datetime >= '2012-01-12 00:00:00' and datetime < '2012-01-19 00:00:00'
group by ztype
;
```

This is based on using sum() as a window aggregate adding 1 for a range start and subtracting 1 for a range end, and then looking for points where the running sum goes to 0 within the target range. I had to do much the same thing as wildplasser did, add a couple of extra entries that don't contribute anything at the endpoints of the boundary so that groups where there is nothing covering the boundary are found...

This seems to cost less on the test data, but I think it might be highly dependent on not having much data in the tables to go through. With some rearranging (which would make it even harder to read) it can work off just two full scans of tmp.gaps (one of which is just getting distinct ztypes).

Comment: did you mean to add a "-1"? select ztype, count(*)-1 as gaps ... thanks!

Comment: BTW: this does not seem right for overlapping stretches. and: CTEs are always faster :-]

Answer (score 2):

Just to avoid double work, here is the data (I replaced the inclusive upper boundary bay an exclusive one, which is more common, IMHO):

```
-- CREATE SCHEMA tmp;
DROP TABLE tmp.gaps CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE tmp.gaps
        ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY       -- surrogate key
        , ztype CHAR(1) NOT NULL
        , start_datetime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL     -- lower boundary := inclusive
        , end_datetime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL       -- upper boundary := exclusive
        );
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX gaps_forward ON tmp.gaps(ztype,start_datetime);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX gaps_backward ON tmp.gaps(ztype,end_datetime);

INSERT INTO tmp.gaps(id,ztype,start_datetime,end_datetime) VALUES
 (1,'a', '2012-01-11 00:00:00', '2012-01-15 00:00:00' )
,(2,'a', '2012-01-18 00:00:00', '2012-01-21 00:00:00' )
,(3,'b', '2012-01-14 00:00:00', '2012-01-20 00:00:00' )
,(4,'c', '2012-01-10 00:00:00', '2012-01-16 00:00:00' )
,(5,'d', '2012-01-11 00:00:00', '2012-01-21 00:00:00' )
,(6,'e', '2012-01-11 00:00:00', '2012-01-15 00:00:00' ) -- added this
,(7,'e', '2012-01-15 00:00:00', '2012-01-21 00:00:00' ) -- and this
        ;
-- SELECT * FROM tmp.gaps;
```

UPDATE: here comes the CTE.
In the first UNION, I add two fake intervals to the left and to the right of the wanted (12-Jan -- 19-Jan) interval.

Per ztype I count the total number of intervals. This should be one if there are no holes, two if there is one hole, etcetera. This also will find gaps for ztype's that don't have any records in the wanted interval.

```
-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
WITH RECURSIVE meuk(ztype,start_datetime,end_datetime) AS (
        -- For every possible "ztype" add two dummie records
        -- just before and just after our wanted interval.
        WITH plus2 AS (
                SELECT g0.ztype,g0.start_datetime,g0.end_datetime FROM tmp.gaps g0
                WHERE (g0.start_datetime <= '2012-01-12 00:00:00' AND g0.end_datetime >= '2012-01-12 00:00:00')
                   OR (g0.start_datetime >= '2012-01-12 00:00:00' AND g0.end_datetime <= '2012-01-19 00:00:00')
                   OR (g0.start_datetime <= '2012-01-19 00:00:00' AND g0.end_datetime >= '2012-01-19 00:00:00')
                UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT g1.ztype, '1900-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp, '2012-01-12 00:00:00'::timestamp FROM tmp.gaps g1
                UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT g2.ztype, '2012-01-19 00:00:00'::timestamp, '2100-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp FROM tmp.gaps g2
                )
        SELECT p0.ztype,p0.start_datetime,p0.end_datetime
        FROM plus2 p0
                -- the start of a stretch: there is no older overlapping 
                -- (or touching) interval
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM plus2 nx
                WHERE nx.ztype = p0.ztype
                AND nx.start_datetime < p0.start_datetime -- older
                AND nx.end_datetime >= p0.start_datetime  -- touching or overlapping
                )
        UNION
        SELECT mk.ztype
                , LEAST(mk.start_datetime,p1.start_datetime)
                , GREATEST(mk.end_datetime,p1.end_datetime)
        FROM plus2 p1
        , meuk mk
        WHERE p1.ztype = mk.ztype
        AND (p1.start_datetime >= mk.start_datetime AND p1.start_datetime <= mk.end_datetime AND p1.end_datetime > mk.end_datetime)
        )
SELECT ztype, COUNT(*)-1 AS ngap
FROM meuk mk
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM meuk  nx
        WHERE nx.ztype = mk.ztype
        AND (nx.start_datetime,nx.end_datetime) OVERLAPS( mk.start_datetime,mk.end_datetime)
        AND (nx.end_datetime - nx.start_datetime) > (mk.end_datetime - mk.start_datetime)
        )
GROUP BY ztype
ORDER BY ztype
        ;
```

Creating the final sum is left as an exercise to the reader ;-)

RESULTS:

```
 ztype | ngap 
-------+------
 a     |    1
 b     |    1
 c     |    1
 d     |    0
 e     |    0
(5 rows)
```