# Plot a graph of the number of people online between a time range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database model that stores

- visit time
- last seen time
- how many seconds online (derived value, calculated by subtracting last seen time from visit time)

I need to build a graph of online people for a time range (say 8pm to 9pm). I'm thinking of the x-axis as the time with the y-axis as the number of people. The granularity is 1 minute for the graph, but I have data granular to 5 seconds.

I can't just sum the seconds online value because people visit before or after 8pm.

I was thinking of just loading up all records found in a particular day and doing calculations in memory (which I would probably do for now, then just cache the derived values for later) but I wanted to know if there's a more efficient way?

I wonder if there's a special sql query group by thing I can do to make this work.

Edit: Here's a graphical representation I am stealing from another question ([Count Grouped Gaps In Time For Time Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800253/count-grouped-gaps-in-time-for-time-range?rq=1)) :P

```
   |.=========]
                     |.=============]
            |=========.======]
|===.=================.====]
   |.=================.==========]

T   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

The bars represent the data I've stored (visit time, last seen time, and seconds online) and I need to know at a particular point how many are online. In this example for T=0 the number is 3 and for T=9 the number is 4)

Q: I can't understand what you mean with "but I have data granular to 5 seconds", how many records do you store per visit? Can you add some example data?

A: There's only one record per visit. Granular to 5 seconds means I'm storing up to 5 seconds worth of accurate data.

Sample data as requested:

```
id     visit_time      last_seen_time        seconds_online
1      00:00:00        00:00:12              10
2      00:12:41        00:12:47               5
3      00:01:20        00:01:22               0
4      00:01:22        00:01:27               5
```

In this particular case, if I graph the people online at 00:00:00 there would be one person, until 00:00:15 where there would be 0 people:

```
 4|
 3|
 2|      *
 1|*                        *
   -*****-******************-
```

Comment: I can't understand what you mean with "but I have data granular to 5 seconds", how many records do you store per visit? Can you add some example data?

Comment: I've updated the question with the sample data you requested

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting and hard question, if we suppose that the interval of graph should be by hour (for example from 8.00 to 8.59), and the granularity by minute we can leverage the problem by extract this date parts (if you are using postgresql the function to use should be EXTRACT), I also suggest to use Commont Table Expressions.

We can then build a CTE to have first minute and last minute of each visit in the target hour, like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXTRACT(hour FROM visit_time) = 8 
            THEN EXTRACT(minute FROM visit_time) 
            ELSE 0 END AS first_minute,
       CASE WHEN EXTRACT(hour FROM last_seen_time) = 8
            THEN EXTRACT(minute FROM last_seen_time)
            ELSE 59 END AS last_minute
  FROM visit_table
 WHERE EXTRACT(hour FROM visit_time) <= 8 AND EXTRACT(hour FROM last_seen_time) >= 8
```

The number of visitor changes when a new visit begin or a visit ends, so we can build a second CTE from the first to have a list of all minutes where the visitors' number changes, lets name `target` the first CTE, then the latter could be defined as:

```
SELECT first_minute AS minute
  FROM target
UNION
SELECT last_minute AS minute
  FROM target
```

The `UNION` will also eliminate duplicates.
Finally we can join the two tables and count the visitors:

```
WITH target AS (
        SELECT CASE WHEN EXTRACT(hour FROM visit_time) = 8 
                    THEN EXTRACT(minute FROM visit_time) 
                    ELSE 0 END AS first_minute,
               CASE WHEN EXTRACT(hour FROM last_seen_time) = 8
                    THEN EXTRACT(minute FROM last_seen_time)
                    ELSE 59 END AS last_minute
          FROM visit_table
         WHERE     EXTRACT(hour FROM visit_time) <= 8
               AND EXTRACT(hour FROM last_seen_time) >= 8
     ), time_table AS (
        SELECT first_minute AS minute
          FROM target
        UNION
        SELECT last_minute AS minute
          FROM target
     )
SELECT time_table.minute, COUNT(*) AS Users
  FROM target INNER JOIN
       time_table ON time_table.minute BETWEEN target.first_minute
                                           AND target.last_minute
 GROUP BY time_table.minute
 ORDER BY time_table.minute
```

You should obtain a table where the first record contains the first minute, within the target hour, when there is at least an online visitor, with the number of online people, then you have a record for each change of the number of online people, with the minute of the change and the new number of online people, you can easily make your graph from this.

Sorry if I can't test this solution, but I hope it could help you anyway.

Comment: Interesting use of SQL :) I'll try it out, but I'm still open to other solutions if you don't mind :)